# Client certificate gets "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel"

Tags: httpclient, x509certficiate2

A few years ago I worked through getting our code to include a client certificate. (see the last post on [Elasticsearch NEST HttpClientHandler Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43125310/elasticsearch-nest-httpclienthandler-certificate)). I am trying to use the same code in another project, but it is failing with:

```
"ExceptionMessage": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."
```

Most suggestions all revolve around setting ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = Tls12; and I have tried all the combinations of that.

I tried to narrow down the scope and simply added the

> Using a HttpClientHandler directly

Example from https://damienbod.com/2019/09/07/using-certificate-authentication-with-ihttpclientfactory-and-httpclient/

```
private async Task<JsonDocument> GetApiDataUsingHttpClientHandler()
{
    var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(_environment.ContentRootPath, "sts_dev_cert.pfx"), "1234");
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
    var client = new HttpClient(handler);
     
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage()
    {
        RequestUri = new Uri("https://localhost:44379/api/values"),
        Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    };
    var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var data = JsonDocument.Parse(responseContent);
        return data;
    }
 
    throw new ApplicationException($"Status code: {response.StatusCode}, Error: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
}
```

This does the entire thing (read cert, attach to handler, and make the request) all in one method. If I run this code in a stand alone project, it works fine. I am trying to run it from a WebApi hosted in Service Fabric. When debugging, I can see that the certificate is obtained and correctly added to the handler. The call never gets out of my code (i.e. never made) as verified with Fiddler.

We are doing this exact thing in Service Fabric in another solution and things work fine.

Is there something else that might be missing?

Thanks!

P.S. Adding full exception

```
{
    "Message": "An error has occurred.",
    "ExceptionMessage": "An error occurred while sending the request.",
    "ExceptionType": "System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException",
    "StackTrace": "   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()",
    "InnerException": {
        "Message": "An error has occurred.",
        "ExceptionMessage": "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.",
        "ExceptionType": "System.Net.WebException",
        "StackTrace": "   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By comparing our two solutions I found something that fixed it. I have no idea what voodoo this is actually doing, but it works. I assume it needs some kind of user context to open the channel.

In the AppManifest.xml for the Service Fabric project, I added this bit of goo at the bottom:

```
  <Principals>
    <Users>
      <User Name="SomeUserName">
        <MemberOf>
          <SystemGroup Name="Administrators" />
        </MemberOf>
      </User>
    </Users>
  </Principals>
  <Policies>
    <DefaultRunAsPolicy UserRef="SomeUserName" />
  </Policies>
```

Note that "SomeUserName" does not actually correspond to any user account on my system. Perhaps it is creating a user context in memory.